# Karma tests failing only in build process

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular8, karma-coverage

I have an issue regarding some failing tests, this would be the only error I get:
**UPDATE:**

```
   + yarn test:customer:jenkins
yarn run v1.16.0
$ ng test aok-customer-lib --code-coverage --configuration=jenkins
[32m26 03 2020 14:26:10.284:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v4.3.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[32m26 03 2020 14:26:10.296:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
[91m26 03 2020 14:26:10.477:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot load browser "ChromeHeadless"!
  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.match (<anonymous>)
    at /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/annotation.js:30:17
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/annotation.js:29:42)
    at Array.invoke (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:69:46)
    at Injector.get (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at module.(anonymous function) (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:253:64)
    at Array.invoke (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at module.(anonymous function) (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:253:64)
    at Array.invoke (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at module.(anonymous function) (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:253:64)
    at Array.invoke (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at module.(anonymous function) (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:253:64)
[91m26 03 2020 14:26:10.478:ERROR [karma-server]: [39mError: Found 1 load error
    at Server.webServer.listen (/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/tmp_frontend_compile/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:192:27)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1314:10)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

And I have tried dozen of configs and now I have alot of flags and maybe not so usefull things in my karma file:

```
    // Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul', 'dots'],
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage/aok-customer-lib'),
      reports: ['lcov', 'cobertura', 'text-summary'],
      thresholds: {
        statements: 80,
        lines: 80,
        branches: 60,
        functions: 80
      }
    },
    files: [
      { pattern:'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js', watched: false, included: false, served: false }
      ],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--no-gpu',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9876',
          '--enable-logging',
          '--v=1'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

There are about 600-700 tests that run here, and in the build process another 1000ish from other project files that do not fail, just this one has issues.
Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please show us the failing tests?

Comment: It's with the error posted in this question on the top